# count number based on values

Tags: javascript

Given this URL

```
https://www.rositarococo.com/gracias.html?hwA-qty-andrea-cobre=2&hwA-qty-sol=1&hwA-qty-valen=1&hwA-qty-mo%C3%B1o-2=1&entry.1471599855=38-andrea-cobre%2C%2037-mo%C3%B1o-2%2C%2036-sol%2C%2036-valen%2C%20&entry.1460904554=sebastian%20flichtentrei&entry.53830725=1156566&entry.1465946249=sflich86%40gmail.com&entry.978809450=TARJETA%20DE%20CR%C3%89DITO&entry.951592426=lavalle%20322&entry.1743418466=ramos%20mejia&entry.59648134=bs%20as&entry.1005165410=1704&entry.541001873=32420573&entry.17650825=A%20DOMICILIO&entry.1209868979=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rositarococo.com%2F&fvv=1&fbzx=5661184097173102736&pageHistory=0
```

There are several parameters given by different names thas contain "qty"

I want to be able to count the values of every parameter with "qty"

On this example would be

```
hwA-qty-andrea-cobre=2
hwA-qty-sol=1
hwA-qty-valen=1
hwA-qty-mo%C3%B1o-2=1
```

Result would be: 5

I dont know how to select all parameter's values that contain "qty"

To access the URL parameters i use:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
};
```

But then i dont know how to access all the parameters which contain qty and sum up all the values together in a variable, maybe using wildcards?

```
var qtyparameter = getUrlParameter('*qty*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression and the `.test()` method.

Since you want to get all the parameters that match, you can't return immediately when a parameter matches, you need to return an array of all of the values.

```
function getMatchingUrlParameters(regexp) {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i,
    results = {};

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0].test(regexp)) {
      results[sParameterName[0]] = decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Then you can call

```
var qtyParams = getMatchingUrlParameters(/-qty-/);
```

and the result will be:

```
{
  "hwA-qty-andrea-cobre": "2",
  "hwA-qty-sol": "1",
  "hwA-qty-valen": "1",
  "hwA-qty-mo%C3%B1o-2": "1"
}
```

You can then add up all the values of the property.

Comment: how would u add up all the values so the result would the 5 in a variable?

Comment: Loop over all the properties, call `parseInt()` on the values, and add them to a variable. What part of that don't you know how to do?